# How to change the description (text) of a layer in the Leaflet Layer Control?

Tags: leaflet, layer-control

In the [Layer Groups and Layers Control](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) tutorial, you first create the "cities" object, and add it to the overlayMaps group control with the "Cities" label name.

```
var baseMaps = {
    "Grayscale": grayscale,
    "Streets": streets
};
var overlayMaps = {
    "Cities": cities
};
```

Is it possible to programatically change the "Cities" label (as seen in the checkbox) to "Cities (zoom in)"?

The reason I want to do this is because I'm "turning on/off" the layer at a specific zoom level by using "clearLayers" method, which leaves the checkbox turned on if the user has already checked it on.

So I am looking for a way to alert the user they need to zoom in to view the layer.

Comment: Can you remove the layer control, and add a new layer control with a different name? or are you looking for a more elegant/robust solution?

Comment: That was my initial thought, too.  However, after I tried this, I realized I didn't want to remove and re-add the layer, because it would uncheck the layer.  Once the user checks the layer object on, I want it to stay on, regardless of of whether or not I am "hiding" the display of the features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe i'm not understanding correctly what you need, but if you only need to change the label, you just can access to the DOM to modify it.

To simplify it a bit, remember that you can use html in the label so:

```
var overlays = {
    "<span id='cities'>Cities</span>": cities
};

document.getElementById('cities').innerHTML = '"Cities (zoom in)"';
```

If you want to change the name when the user (un)checks the checkbox, you can register a callback to the overlayadd, overlayremove events.

```
map.on('overlayadd', function() {
    document.getElementById('cities').innerHTML = '"Cities (zoom in)"';
});

 map.on('overlayadd', function() {
    document.getElementById('cities').innerHTML = 'Cities';
});
```

Comment: I'll need to test it out, but I think you've described what I was looking for.  I had found the `document.getElementById('cities').innerHTML` code, but your suggestion to embed the HTML `<span id='value'>` is the missing piece I was struggling with.  I'll use that to help manage the "finding" of the correct label.  Thank you!